# ConnectedRouter A <Router> may have only one child element but it has one child

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

So I have my `App.tsx`
I use switch from react-router 4

```
import { Rate } from 'antd'
import * as React from 'react'
import './App.scss'

import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router' // react-router v4

class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div> { /* your usual react-router v4 routing */}
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<div>Match</div>)} />
            <Route render={() => (<div>Miss</div>)} />
            <Rate />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

And I have `index.tsx` like this
Here I use connected-react-router to connect to redux.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import './index.scss'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

import store, { history } from './store'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}> { /* place ConnectedRouter under Provider */}
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
)
registerServiceWorker()
```

As you can see Router indeed has just one element however I get an error that the router should have only one child. Is this a bug of connected-react-router or am I just missing something in here?

Comment: I think the problem is the comment, move it before the `ConnectedRouter`

Comment: @PatrickHund yup, add answer to accept

Comment: Done. It surprised me too that comments count as children

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment inside the `ConnectedRouter` component causes the problem. As it turns out, comments also count as children. Fix it by moving the comment one line above:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    { /* place ConnectedRouter under Provider */}
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
)
```